# Insertar variable de Javascript a un Form action. con pug/jade

Tags: javascript, jade, pug

Estoy necesitando insertar el valor de una variable de javascript al `action` de un formulario

el Script es este:

```
    var url = window.location;
    var urlcomplete = url.href;
    var urlparts = urlcomplete.split("/");
    var years = urlparts[urlparts.length - 1];
    var route = "/app/imagenes/"+years; //variable a pasar
```

el form es este:

```
    form(action="//AQUI QUIERO INSERTAR EL VALOR DE LA VARIABLE//" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del archivo pug, las variables han de ir con un guión delante, de tal modo que:

```
- var url = window.location;
- var urlcomplete = url.href;
- var urlparts = urlcomplete.split("/");
- var years = urlparts[urlparts.length - 1]; 
- var route = "/app/imagenes/"+years; //variable a pasar 

form(action=route method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
```

Tienes el ejemplo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YeqPJZ

**Editado**

En este caso, location.href no lo va a encontrar. Para poder cambiar el href del formularío se tiene que recurrir a crear un codigo de javascript. 
En jade, para que genere un script se utiliza la etiqueta `script.` (observese el punto final), de esta manera lo que esté tabulado en su interior será codigo javascript.

Podemos utilizar esto para crear el formularío y despues establecerle el action por medio de javascript:

```
form(id="formr" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
script.  
   var url = window.location;
   var urlcomplete = url.href;
   var urlparts = urlcomplete.split("/");
   var years = urlparts[urlparts.length - 1]; 
   var route = "/app/imagenes/"+years; //variable a pasar 

   document.getElementeById('formr').action = route
```

Dado que `location.href` es una variable de entorno, es el navegador quien se ocupa de ella. No jade